# Нужно сделать сортировку значений которые находятся в таблице по клику

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

я не могу немножко разобраться в Ajax и перебросом знчений переменных из php в jquery.
Вопрос следующий, как мне перебросить массив который удовлетворен php в js, там его отсортировать как DESC, по убыванию, и вернуть в том же формате в котором он пришел, только чтобы он заполнил ячейки наоборот, не от 1 до 25, а от 25 до 1. Потестировал, запрос работает по клику, нажимаю на ссылку сверху, все значения меняются на "data". Вообщем нужно принять jq значения переменной, отсортировать, и вывести как отсортированные, вот ниже код,

```
/* PHP */
//Допустим это данные
 $cars = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `Cars` "); // Got Object with values (keys,values)
 $cars = mysqli_fetch_all($cars); // replace Object to array[array]  ( [ [0] [1] [2] [3]... ] )

 foreach($cars as $car) {                 // Output values of database
                    // $result = "SELECT $car[0] FROM `cars` ORDER BY `cars`.`$car[0]` DESC";
                     //echo $result;
                     $carJson = json_encode($car[0]);
                     print_r($carJson);
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="carReverse" data-car="<?=$carJson?>"><?=$car[0]?></td>
                        <td><?=$car[1]?></td>
                        <td><?=$car[2]?></td>
                        <td><?=$car[3]?></td>
                        <td><?=$car[4]?></td>
                        <td><?=$car[5]?></td>
                        <td><?=$car[6]?></td>
                    </tr>

                <?php
}
        ?>

/* Jquery */
    let car = $("[data-car]");
    let sort = $("[data-sort]");
    let sortt = [];
    sort.on("click", function(e) { // On click
        e.preventDefault();
        $("[data-car]").each( function() {
            let res = $(this).data("car");
            
            sortt.push(res);
            sortt.sort( (a,b) => b - a);
            console.log(sortt);

            $.ajax({  // Send Ajax request
                type: "POST", // Type (POST, GET, PUT, etc)
                url: "../phpDBdatas/cars.php", //URL out processing
                data: {data: JSON.stringify(sortt)},
                success: (data) => {
                  $('.carReverse').html("data");   
                },
        });
        });
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, пробовал json, но у меня не хватает знаний пока все это в голове сопоставить, как можно принять данные jquery с сохранением удовлетворенного массива php, и вернуть не повредив его, и поставить в ячейки по клику. Спасибо, буду очень рад конструктивным ответам, желательно разжевывая.

Comment: Зачем это все отправлять запросом? JS вполне может и сам отсортировать ячейки.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, как мне это сделать если у меня один столбец, а в нем по циклу находится 25 ячеек                                                 <td class="carReverse" data-car="<?=$carJson?>"><?=$car[0]?></td> - А мне нужно взаимодействовать с каждым, по классу всем столбцам добавляется 25, я уже отсортировал пришедшие значения, принял их data-car со значением <?=$car[0]?> из цикла, как мне в каждую ячейку перенести отсортированное значение ?